# Parpadear LIBDGX

Tags: java, android, libgdx

Hola tengo el siguiente código:

```
package cat.xtec.ioc.screens;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Input;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Screen;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Color;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Batch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.GlyphLayout;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.ShapeRenderer;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Action;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Stage;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.actions.Actions;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.actions.SequenceAction;
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.viewport.Viewport;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import cat.xtec.ioc.helpers.AssetManager;
import cat.xtec.ioc.helpers.InputHandler;
import cat.xtec.ioc.objects.Asteroid;
import cat.xtec.ioc.objects.ScrollHandler;
import cat.xtec.ioc.objects.Spacecraft;
import cat.xtec.ioc.utils.Settings;

public class GameScreen implements Screen {

    // Els estats del joc
    public enum GameState {

        READY, RUNNING, GAMEOVER , PAUSE

    }

    private GameState currentState;

    // Objectes necessaris
    private Stage stage;
    private Spacecraft spacecraft;
    private ScrollHandler scrollHandler;

    // Encarregats de dibuixar elements per pantalla
    private ShapeRenderer shapeRenderer;
    private Batch batch;

    // Per controlar l'animació de l'explosió
    private float explosionTime = 0;

    // Preparem el textLayout per escriure text
    private GlyphLayout textLayout;

    public GameScreen(Batch prevBatch, Viewport prevViewport) {

        // Iniciem la música
        AssetManager.music.play();

        // Creem el ShapeRenderer
        shapeRenderer = new ShapeRenderer();

        // Creem l'stage i assginem el viewport
        stage = new Stage(prevViewport, prevBatch);

        batch = stage.getBatch();

        // Creem la nau i la resta d'objectes
        spacecraft = new Spacecraft(Settings.SPACECRAFT_STARTX, Settings.SPACECRAFT_STARTY, Settings.SPACECRAFT_WIDTH, Settings.SPACECRAFT_HEIGHT);
        scrollHandler = new ScrollHandler();

        // Afegim els actors a l'stage
        stage.addActor(scrollHandler);
        stage.addActor(spacecraft);
        // Donem nom a l'Actor
        spacecraft.setName("spacecraft");

        // Iniciem el GlyphLayout
        textLayout = new GlyphLayout();
        textLayout.setText(AssetManager.font, "Are you\nready?");


        currentState = GameState.READY;


        // Assignem com a gestor d'entrada la classe InputHandler
        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(new InputHandler(this));

    }

    private void drawElements() {

        // Recollim les propietats del Batch de l'Stage
        shapeRenderer.setProjectionMatrix(batch.getProjectionMatrix());

        // Inicialitzem el shaperenderer
        shapeRenderer.begin(ShapeRenderer.ShapeType.Line);

        // Definim el color (verd)
        shapeRenderer.setColor(new Color(0, 1, 0, 1));

        // Pintem la nau
        shapeRenderer.rect(spacecraft.getX(), spacecraft.getY(), spacecraft.getWidth(), spacecraft.getHeight());

        // Recollim tots els Asteroid
        ArrayList<Asteroid> asteroids = scrollHandler.getAsteroids();
        Asteroid asteroid;

        for (int i = 0; i < asteroids.size(); i++) {

            asteroid = asteroids.get(i);
            switch (i) {
                case 0:
                    shapeRenderer.setColor(1, 0, 0, 1);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    shapeRenderer.setColor(0, 0, 1, 1);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    shapeRenderer.setColor(1, 1, 0, 1);
                    break;
                default:
                    shapeRenderer.setColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
                    break;
            }
            shapeRenderer.circle(asteroid.getX() + asteroid.getWidth() / 2, asteroid.getY() + asteroid.getWidth() / 2, asteroid.getWidth() / 2);
        }
        shapeRenderer.end();
    }


    @Override
    public void show() {

    }

    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {

        // Dibuixem tots els actors de l'stage
        stage.draw();

        // Depenent de l'estat del joc farem unes accions o unes altres
        switch (currentState) {

            case GAMEOVER:
                updateGameOver(delta);
                break;
            case RUNNING:
                updateRunning(delta);
                break;
            case READY:
                updateReady();
                break;
            //TODO UBIQUEM LA PAUSA DE TAL FORMA QUE SIGUI UNA OPCIÓ
            case PAUSE:
               updatePause(delta);

        }

        //drawElements();

    }

    private void updateReady() {

        // Dibuixem el text al centre de la pantalla
        batch.begin();
        AssetManager.font.draw(batch, textLayout, (Settings.GAME_WIDTH / 2) - textLayout.width / 2, (Settings.GAME_HEIGHT / 2) - textLayout.height / 2);
        //stage.addActor(textLbl);
        batch.end();

    }
    // TODO EXERCICI 2
    // Creem la pantalla PAUSE
    private void updatePause( float delta) {

        SequenceAction actions = Actions.sequence(Actions.run(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                spacecraft.setVisible(true);
                spacecraft.setVisible(false);
            }
        }),Actions.delay(.2f),Actions.run(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        spacecraft.setVisible(false);
                        spacecraft.setVisible(true);
                    }
                }), Actions.delay(0.f));

        Action myAction = Actions.forever(actions);
        stage.addAction(myAction);

        textLayout.setText(AssetManager.font,"Pause");
        if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.SPACE)){
    currentState = GameState.READY;

    }    }

    private void updateRunning(float delta) {
        stage.act(delta);

        if (scrollHandler.collides(spacecraft)) {
            // Si hi ha hagut col·lisió: Reproduïm l'explosió i posem l'estat a GameOver
            AssetManager.explosionSound.play();
            stage.getRoot().findActor("spacecraft").remove();
            textLayout.setText(AssetManager.font, "Game Over :'(");
            currentState = GameState.GAMEOVER;
            // TODO EXERCICI 2 he trobat aquesta forma de pausar.. Si dono al SPACE.. vaig a la pantalla updatePause
        }else if (Gdx.input.isKeyJustPressed(Input.Keys.SPACE)){
            currentState = GameState.PAUSE;


                    }
    }



    private void updateGameOver(float delta) {
        stage.act(delta);

        batch.begin();
        AssetManager.font.draw(batch, textLayout, (Settings.GAME_WIDTH - textLayout.width) / 2, (Settings.GAME_HEIGHT - textLayout.height) / 2);
        // Si hi ha hagut col·lisió: Reproduïm l'explosió i posem l'estat a GameOver
        batch.draw(AssetManager.explosionAnim.getKeyFrame(explosionTime, false), (spacecraft.getX() + spacecraft.getWidth() / 2) - 32, spacecraft.getY() + spacecraft.getHeight() / 2 - 32, 64, 64);
        batch.end();

        explosionTime += delta;

    }

    public void reset() {

        // Posem el text d'inici
        textLayout.setText(AssetManager.font, "Are you\nready?");
        // Cridem als restart dels elements.
        spacecraft.reset();
        scrollHandler.reset();

        // Posem l'estat a 'Ready'
        currentState = GameState.READY;

        // Afegim la nau a l'stage
        stage.addActor(spacecraft);

        // Posem a 0 les variables per controlar el temps jugat i l'animació de l'explosió
        explosionTime = 0.0f;

    }


    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {

    }

    @Override
    public void pause() {

    }

    @Override
    public void resume() {

    }

    @Override
    public void hide() {

    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {

    }

    public Spacecraft getSpacecraft() {
        return spacecraft;
    }

    public Stage getStage() {
        return stage;
    }

    public ScrollHandler getScrollHandler() {
        return scrollHandler;
    }

    public GameState getCurrentState() {
        return currentState;
    }

    public void setCurrentState(GameState currentState) {
        this.currentState = currentState;
    }
}
```

El problema lo tengo con la siguiente parte del código:

```
  SequenceAction actions = Actions.sequence(Actions.run(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            spacecraft.setVisible(true);
            spacecraft.setVisible(false);
        }
    }),Actions.delay(.2f),Actions.run(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    spacecraft.setVisible(false);
                    spacecraft.setVisible(true);
                }
            }), Actions.delay(0.f));

    Action myAction = Actions.forever(actions);
    stage.addAction(myAction);

    textLayout.setText(AssetManager.font,"Pause");
    if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.SPACE)){
currentState = GameState.READY;
```

Básicamente necesito que los objetos que estan en pausa parpadean,he conseguido hacerlo pero solo lo hace cuando esta en funcionamiento en juego. Necesito que lo haga pero cuando la pantalla este en pausa es decir updatePause()

gracias!

Comment: [Android Studio](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/android-studio/info): Utilizar esta etiqueta solo si la pregunta está asociada al uso, funcionalidades o problemas con el IDE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema esta que tu haces:

```
spacecraft.setVisible(true);
spacecraft.setVisible(false);
```

el problema con eso es que el tiempo es demasiado corto como para que el ojo
humano lo note.

puedes hacerlo sin tantas complicaciones...
lo que hace el código es parpadear durante este en modo pausa

```
Action act = Actions.run(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {

        final double steep = 1000 * 0.2;

        while(currentState == GameState.PAUSE)
        {
            spacecraft.setVisible(true);

            try {
                Thread.steep((long)steep);
            }catch(InterruptedException e){}

            spacecraft.setVisible(false);

            try {
                Thread.steep((long)steep);
            }catch(InterruptedException e){}
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No deberías dormir este Thread, es el mismo que se encarga de correr el juego. Por supuesto esta en Pausa, pero si al tocar un boton como por ejemplo "Resume"  y el Thread esta durmiendo, este botón no va a responder.

La manera correcta seria:

```
imagenQueParpadea.addAction(Actions.forever(Actions.sequence(
    Actions.delay(0.5f,Actions.visible(false)),
    Actions.delay(0.5f,Actions.visible(true))
)));
```

Puedes tambien utilizar fadeOut y fadeIn...

```
imagenQueParpadea.addAction(Actions.forever(Actions.sequence(
    Actions.delay(0.5f,Actions.fadeOut(0.2f)),
    Actions.delay(0.5f,Actions.fadeIn(0.2f))
)));
```

O simplemente hacer fadeOut y fadeIn, **sin el delay**

```
imagenQueParpadea.addAction(Actions.forever(Actions.sequence(
    Actions.fadeOut(0.5f)),
    Actions.fadeIn(0.5f))
)));
```

y se veria algo asi

```
  // este metodo ya lo tienes, solo tienes que añardirle esto
  public void setCurrentState(GameState currentState) {
     this.currentState = currentState;
    
     //solo si el nuevo gamestate es PAUSE empieza a parpadear
     if(currentState == GameState.PAUSE){
         spacecraft.addAction(Actions.forever(Actions.sequence(
             Actions.fadeOut(0.5f)),
             Actions.fadeIn(0.5f))
         )));
     }
     else spacecraft.clearActions();

  }
```

**Notas:**

- Estoy suponiendo que la clase `Spacecraft` extiende `Actor` para que puedas usar `spacecraft.addAction()`
- Tienes que cambiar todas las lineas en las cuales asignas currentState asi `currentState = GameState.PAUSE;` y cambiarlas por `setCurrentState(GameState.PAUSE);`

¿Ya vez lo importante que es cuando te dijeron que es buena practica usar setters?